# Why HtmlCompat.fromHtml() is not styling the text?

Tags: android, xml, string, kotlin

I am trying to style a part of `String` before setting it to `TextView`. But when I run the application, no styling is applied to the text.

I have defined the string resource in *strings.xml* as

```
<string name="amount_added_notice"> <![CDATA[Amount of <b><font color=\'#333333\'>\u20B9%1$s</font></b> added to %2$s Account]]> </string>
```

In the `XML`, I am using `DataBinding` to set text

```
android:text="@{viewModel.firstText}"
```

The `firstText` variable is defined in `ViewModel` as

```
val firstText by lazy { ObservableField<String>() }
```

And then the `string` is assigned as follows,

```
firstText.set(  HtmlCompat.fromHtml(context.getString(R.string.amount_added_notice, "500", "John's"), FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you edit you question and share ,how do you setText for `TextView`

Comment: Paste the html String directly to `fromHtml` instead of using `context.getString` that will prove if the problem is the `fromHtml` or `context.getString` (I have a feel your problem is the escaping of the HTML in the XML file).

Comment: I have added the XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
val firstText by lazy { ObservableField<String>() }
```

Try changing that to:

```
val firstText by lazy { ObservableField<CharSequence>() }
```

and see if that helps. The output of `HtmlCompat.fromHtml()` is a `CharSequence`, specifically some sort of `Spannable` that contains the formatting rules. My guess is that is is getting down-converted into a plain `String`.

Comment: Yes, indeed changing that to `CharSequence` worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the single quotes and backslashes around your hex color.
Like that

```
<font color=#333333>
```

Comment: I will try that for sure, but what about the text not being bold?